# How to deselect all other checkboxes when one is selected

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I’m writing a simple macro and am a bit rusty in my VBA skills. The macro has a list of options with “yes”, “no” and “maybe” options to choose from. I used checkboxes rather than option buttons so each option doesn’t have to be in an individual frame.

The code I have written (below) deselects the other options when one is selected, but I have to select it again for it to actually be selected which will be frustrating for the user.

```
Private Sub Yes_Click()
     No.Value = False
     Maybe.Value = False
End Sub
```

I have tried adding the additional line

```
Yes.Value = True
```

But this then crashes excel when the macro is run.

I can’t find any advice for this problem so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe option buttons would be better since that's what they are designed for?

Comment: CheckBox (≙ multiple selections possible) vs. OptionBox (≙ only single selection possible). If you choose the right box no VBA code is needed.

Comment: 1- Options buttons are the way to go. You don't need to make the container visible (it can be a frame without borders, and I think there is others containers working). 2- Click event for the checkbox is triggered both when the check is put and when it's removed. You can check the current value of the checkbox to adapt your behavior. Setting the value inside the even will trigger the event that will trigger the event... infinily, hence the crash.

Comment: There are about 17 items that the user needs to select yes, no or maybe for which makes the form extremely cluttered with 17 frames to use option buttons. This is why I was looking for a way to do it with the checkboxes

Comment: @Georgina What about invisible frames? The alternative would be your code will be extremely cluttered. Other alternative: Use 1 ComboBox instead of 3 Check/OptionBoxes and this will reduce your controls a lot.

Comment: Thanks everyone, didn’t realise frames could be invisible!

Comment: @Georgina just remove the caption of the frame and set its `SpecialEffect` to `0 - fmSpecialEffectFlat`.

Comment: In addition to the suggested use of a combobox by @Pᴇʜ, you can also use a listbox with the "Option list" style.